# How Do I Count Occurrences in a Column in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table that lists the following values. Some of the values in column 1 show up twice for the same customer (for example `apple` could show up 2 or more times.)

```
Column 1
Apples
Oranges
Bananas
```

I know I can use this to get the count for each of the values.

```
SELECT column 1, COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY column 1
```

Is there a way to write a SQL statement that looks at when the count of one of those values shows up twice for the same customer?

For example, I want to find out how many times apple shows up twice for the same customer.

Comment: `having count(*) > 1`?

Comment: Thank you so much. I will give that a try. I forgot about the Having clause.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a customer column, your query could look like this:

```
SELECT customer, column1, COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY customer, column1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

This will show you a customer field, and your column1 (the column with Apple and Banana and so on), and the number of times the combination of these fields occur.
The `GROUP BY` will ensure that the count is calculated correctly.
The `HAVING` will only show records where the `COUNT` value is > 1 after the grouping has occurred.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will give that a try. I forgot about the Having clause.